# Odoo hide button in tree view on edit mode

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have form view and inside it one2many relation with tree view. I want to hide or disable `"do_work"` button on edit mode.
I noticed what I can hide button if it is not in tree view on edit mode by `class="oe_edit_only"`. But is it possible to hide or disable it in tree view because the same class doesn't work for me?

```
<field name="new_line">
       <tree editable="bottom">
             <field name="name"/>
             <field name="quantity"/>
             <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
             <field name="vendor"/>
             <field name="price_unit"/>
             <button name="do_work" type="object" string="Copy"/>
     </tree>
</field>
```

Your advice or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this could work from that context but you could try:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('id', '>', 0)]}"
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: If I use this field attribute it always hides button. Doesn't matter is it edit mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

Class and style are ignored in tree view so there is no easy way to do it.

But you can create your own css to target the button with that name and use same css as eo_edit_only. Or you can look if there is a module for in odoo apps.

Comment: Thank you. I can't find any apps. Talking about css do mean this way below?

Comment: css:
.myBtn {
  display: none !important;
}
and xml:
<button name="do_work" type="object" string="Copy" class="myBtn"/>
But ir doesn't work.